# Pandas row manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace a row in a dataframe with the row of another dataframe only if they share a common column.
Here is the first dataframe:

```
index    no foo
0        0   1
1        1   2
2        2   3
3        3   4
4        4   5
5        5   6
```

and the second dataframe:

```
index    no foo
0        2  aaa
1        3  bbb
2       22    3
3       33    4
4       44    5
5       55    6
```

I'd like my result to be

```
index    no foo
0        0   1
1        1   2
2        2   aaa
3        3   bbb
4        4   5
5        5   6
```

The result of the inner merge between both dataframes returns the correct rows, but I'm having trouble inserting them at the correct index in the first dataframe
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: this should help... http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work as well

```
df1['foo'] = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='no', how='left').apply(lambda r: r['foo_y'] if r['foo_y'] == r['foo_y'] else r['foo_x'], axis=1)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it merges correctly the values for foo for the right hand side but leaves the other foo values as `NaN`

Comment: You're right, is filling nan on the merged column. Corrected this

Comment: This works great! How would you ensure the integrity of the data if another column was introduced in the original dataframe?

Comment: Let me rephrase, how would you handle replacing more than 1 column in df1 in the event that df1.no == df2.no? I'm interested in inserting rows from df2 into df1 if that condition is met.

Comment: edit 3: I was able to achieve this by simply reiterating your command for the number of columns in need to transfer over from df2 to df1. It runs in about 4 minutes over 4 columns with 2.8 million rows. It's a bit slower than what i'd like but as long as it works!

Comment: One way is to merge index values as well - pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), ...). Then run apply twice to return indices of df1 and df2 as appropriate. You could then select appropriate rows from the two and concatenate pd.concat([df1.ix[ix1], df2.ix[ix2]], ignore_index=True). This might make it faster

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply`, there is probably a better way than this:

```
In [67]:

# define a function that takes a row and tries to find a match
def func(x):
    # find if 'no' value matches, test the length of the series
    if len(df1.loc[df1.no ==x.no, 'foo']) > 0:
        return df1.loc[df1.no ==x.no, 'foo'].values[0] # return the first array value
    else:
        return x.foo # no match so return the existing value

# call apply and using a lamda apply row-wise (axis=1 means row-wise)
df.foo = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
df

Out[67]:

   index  no  foo
0      0   0    1
1      1   1    2
2      2   2  aaa
3      3   3  bbb
4      4   4    5
5      5   5    6

[6 rows x 3 columns]
```